# C++ STL set custom comparator

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

I have a problem in ordering a set of string by custom comparator.
I would order according to string length.

```
struct CompareLenght
{
    bool operator()(const std::string s1, const std::string s2) const
    {return (s1.size()>s2.size());}        
}

class SearchEngine
{
    private:
    void Associate(const std::vector<std::string> &Files);
    public:   
    SearchEngine(const std::vector<std::string> &Files);  
    void Search(const std::string &frase, std::set<std::string> *S);
};

class FindWord
{
    private:
    std::set<std::string> Parole_Univoche; 
    public:  

    FindWord(const std::string &str);
    inline void Get_Word(std::set<std::string> *Set_Of_Word); 
};

inline void FindWord::Get_Word(std::set<std::string> *Set_Of_Word)
{  
    *Set_Of_Word = Parole_Univoche;
}
```

The problem comes when I try to do that:

```
void SearchEngine::Search(const std::string &phrase, std::set<std::string> *S)
{
    FindWord F(phrase);                             
    std::set<std::string,CompareLenght> Keyword;             
    F.Get_Word(&Keyword);   
    // some code
}
```

The error is:

```
In file included from main.cc:15:0:
SearchEngineNew.cc: In member function ‘void SearchEngine::Search(const string&, std::set<std::basic_string<char> >*)’:
SearchEngineNew.cc:69:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘FindWord::Get_Word(std::set<std::basic_string<char>, cmp>*)’
              F.Get_Word(&Keyword);       
                                 ^
SearchEngineNew.cc:69:33: note: candidate is:
In file included from main.cc:14:0:
FindWord.cc:39:13: note: void FindWord::Get_Word(std::set<std::basic_string<char> >*)
 inline void FindWord::Get_Word(std::set<std::string> *Set_Of_Word)
             ^
FindWord.cc:39:13: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::set<std::basic_string<char>, cmp>*’ to ‘std::set<std::basic_string<char> >*’
```

How can solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Also note that your `CompareLenght` (besides having a typo) takes its input by value, which is unnecessary and inefficient. Rather you should change the signature of the comparator to `bool operator()(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined set as

```
std::set<std::string,CompareLenght> Keyword;
```

that is the type of Keyword is `std::set<std::string,CompareLenght>` But function Get_Word has parameter of type `std::set<std::string> *`

```
inline void FindWord::Get_Word(std::set<std::string> *Set_Of_Word)
           {  *Set_Of_Word = Parole_Univoche;}
```

Change it the following way

```
inline void FindWord::Get_Word(std::set<std::string, CompareLenght> *Set_Of_Word)
           {  *Set_Of_Word = Parole_Univoche;}
```

Also it seems the function should be defined as

```
inline void FindWord::Get_Word(std::set<std::string, CompareLenght> *Set_Of_Word)
           {  Parole_Univoche = *Set_Of_Word; }
```

because there is no any sense in the assignment

```
*Set_Of_Word = Parole_Univoche;
```

Also data member

```
std::set<std::string> Parole_Univoche;
```

should be also defined as

```
std::set<std::string, CompareLenght> Parole_Univoche;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing &KeyWord which is of type:

```
std::set<std::string,CompareLenght> Keyword;
```

to method with parameter of type:

```
std::set<std::string>*
```

the difference in those types is the lack of CompareLenght in the Get_Word parameter type. You could make this mathod a template method to accept any type of KeyWord, or add overloaded method. Or simply change Get_Word to:

```
inline void Get_Word(std::set<std::string,CompareLenght> *Set_Of_Word); 
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but you would have to then propagate this change to your Parole_Univoche or copy Set_Of_Word manually like that:

```
typedef std::set<std::string> set_type;
for ( set_type::const_iterator citr = Parole_Univoche.begin(); citr != Parole_Univoche.end(); ++citr ) {
    Set_Of_Word->insert(*citr);
}
```